# Find exact formulas for the integration weights

Tags: real-analysis, integration, numerical-methods

Find exact formulas for the integration weights $w_1, w_2, w_3$ such that $\int_{-1}^1 q(x)dx=\sum_{j=1}^3w_jq(x_j)$ exactly whenever q is a polynomial of degree 5.

Should I start with this: let $q(x)=ax^5+bx^4+...+f$?

Comment: Are the $x_j$ explicitly given?

Comment: Nope... That's why I can't cancel out the terms..